# Erro com os casos de testes

Tags: c

Meu professor recomendou esse site chamado uri, e estou conseguindo resolver algumas questões, só que nessa tentei todas as soluções que a questão colocou e o programa que eu fiz sai as os resultados pedidos na questão, o juiz uri está dando 30 % de erro porém não sei como corrigir o erro.

[Link para a questão.](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1961)

Aqui está o meu código.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int teste, altura, i, maior;
  scanf("%d %d", &altura, &teste);
   int vetor[teste], vetorb[teste], vetorc[teste], c = 0, b = 0, 
   vetorf[teste];
   for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
   {
     scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
   }
   for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
   {
      if(i % 2 == 0)
      {
         vetorc[c++] = vetor[i];
      }
      else
      {
        vetorb[b++] = vetor[i];
      }

   }
   for(i = 0; i < c + b; i++)
   {
     vetorf[i] = vetorb[i] - vetorc[i];
   }
   maior = vetorf[0];
   for(i = 0; i < b; i++)
   {
     if(vetorf[i] > maior)
     {
        maior = vetorf[i];
     }
   }
   if(maior > altura)
   {
      printf("GAME OVER\n");
   }
   else
   {
     printf("YOU WIN\n");
   }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não há razão de procurar-se a altura do maior cano. Fazer isso dá a entender que você não entendeu direito o problema. A única coisa que interessa é a diferença entre as alturas dos canos. O valor absoluto de cada cano não importa. A diferença entre um cano de altura 5 e um de altura 7 é a mesma que entre um cano de altura 10005 e um de altura 10007. Assim, não é para você comparar a altura do cano com a altura do pulo do sapo, pois mesmo se você tiver um cano de altura 1000 e o sapo tem altura do pulo igual a 2, ainda assim está correto se o próximo cano tiver altura 1001 e o anterior 999.

Você declara vários vetores: `vetor`, `vetorb`, `vetorc` e `vetorf`. Apenas um seria suficiente.

Ao fazer isso:

```
for(i = 0; i < c + b; i++)
{
  vetorf[i] = vetorb[i] - vetorc[i];
}
```

Você está verificando a diferença nas alturas entre um cano em posição ímpar do cano em posição par que se segue. Entretanto, isso não verifica a altura entre o cano de posição par do cano em posição ímpar subsequente. Não há razão de separar-se as alturas dos canos pares das alturas dos canos ímpares (`vetorc` e `vetorb`). Seria muito mais fácil fazer isso:

```
for (i = 0; i < teste - 1; i++) {
    vetorf[i] = vetor[i] - vetor[i + 1];
}
```

Entretanto, esse código pode eliminar a necessidade de usar o `vetorf` ao fazer a verificação dentro do `for`:

```
for (i = 0; i < teste - 1; i++) {
    int dif = vetor[i] - vetor[i + 1];
    if (dif < 0) dif = -dif;
    if (dir > altura) {
        printf("GAME OVER\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
printf("YOU WIN\n");
return 0;
```